# Set field accessibility of Custom Setting's field

Tags: customsetting, field-level-security

Can we set field level security / field accessibility of a Custom Setting's field?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot set FLS for custom settings through profiles. If you have `'Customize Application'` permission you can perform CRUD operations through the setup menu.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes I do have Customize Application permission. Please direct form where can I perform CRUD operation.

Comment: You can perform CRUD operations from apex like you update/insert any custom object record. Are you seeing any errors?